# returning a default instance from a getter method that I don't want to persist

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have two domain objects:

```
Customer
CustomerConfig
```

Customer has a 1-1 association with CustomerConfig. There is a default CustomerConfig with default settings for Customers who do not have an explicitly saved CustomerConfig e.g.

```
def getConfig() {
    if (!config) {
        return new CustomerConfig() //the default settings
    } else {
        return config
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that when I return the default setting GORM saves the CustomerConfig instance to the database as it appears to GORM that it has changed.

In fact I do not want to save it to the database as I want to be able to control the default settings for customer and make updates for customers until they have an explicitly saved config.

I also am trying avoid using conditional logic as follows:

```
def config = customer.config?:new CustomerConfig()
```

And encapsulate it in the Customer domain object. It seems like there's a different pattern I should be following. Would welcome any advice.

Thanks,

cowper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, it's never a good idea to change behavior of default getter/setter as those are managed by GORM.

You can do something like this

```
 class Customer {
   static transients = ['setting']

   public CustomerConfig getSetting(){
    return getConfig()?:new CustomerConfig()
}
```